# comparing variables that involve time

Tags: statistical-significance

I need to compare (for statistical significance) hospital admissions and chest infections per year, before and after the  introduction of antibiotic prophylaxis in 100 patents. These are patients that started prophylaxis at various time points in the past 15 years and some of them are not still on them. All of them were prescribed prophylaxis but some only took this for a few months. I need to check whether admissions/ infections were reduced in the group that was on prophylaxis in comparison to those that were not (although these are the same patients- before and after prophylaxis).

What test should I use and would it be easy to apply this in Excel or Graphpad? I think a t test is not ideal in the sense that I am comparing ratios that incorporate time and a patient with 0 infections in 1 month will get the same ratio to a patient with 0 infections in 15 years.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. Could you please articulate what you need to compare exactly? Do you want to compare both variables before and after introducing the drug? Are the 100 patients your full sample space (as in admissions and infection data is for these patients only)?

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean of compare?please explain a bit more about whole your goal in this problem,and describe it.
but ti hope this help you
your data set is a panel data.it means you have cross-section and time series together.
and there are a lot of information about panel data on the internet.

but depends on how many years you have and your variables are in the same years or not,do you have missing values or not ,, approaches can be different.
but almost every test in a crosssection dataset have an adapted version for panel data too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply- hopefully I've made my question more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a [t test](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/t-test/). Split the data so you have, for each patient, a count of their admissions/infections before and after the antibiotics were introduced. Use the t test to compare.

Bear in mind that it may well be that a rise in admissions/infections was what lead to that customer being given the antibiotics in the first place so your 'before' group may be skewed by this.